# best way to count the bigger elements on the right and left side of an array

Tags: php, arrays, code-complexity

For example, in php

```
$arr = [9, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6];
```

then,

```
$output = [[0,0], [1,2], [2,2], [1,1], [4,1], [1,0]];
```

[0, 0] = the bigger elements of 9 is 0 on both side

[1, 2] = the bigger elements of 4 is 1 (9) on left and 2 (5, 6) on right side ... [ 9 > 4] -  [ 5 > 4, 6 > 4 ]

[2, 2] = the bigger elements of 3 is 2 (9, 4) on the left and 2 (5, 6) on right side

[1, 1] = the bigger elements of 5 is 1 (9) on the left and 1 (6) on the right side

[4, 1] = the bigger elements of 2 (9, 4, 3, 5) is 4 on the left and 1 (6) on the right side

[1, 0] = the bigger elements of 6 is 1 (9) on the left and 0 (no elements after 6) on the right side

I want it in O(n log(n)), is it possible?

Comment: What I have done is similar to the answer of #mickadoo with O(n2) complexity

Comment: Well, O(n^2) is soo bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like lots of answers already, you could do this with some of the array functions like some of the answers did, but since this is probably for your homework best to keep it simple. I keep track of whether it's left or right that should be incremented each iteration by using the $side variable.

```
$arr = [9, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6];
$results = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
    $results[$x] = [0,0];
    $side = 0;
    for ($y = 0; $y < count($arr); $y++) {
        if ($arr[$y] > $arr[$x]) {
            $results[$x][$side]++;
        } elseif ($arr[$x] == $arr[$y]) {
            $side = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through `$arr` to get each value, and then, in the loop, loop again through `$arr` to get the other values. Then, in the second loop, you build your output array by comparing both the `value` (to know if the number is, indeed, bigger) and the `key` (to know if it's on the left or the right).

```
$arr = array(9, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6);
$output = array();
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    $out = array(0, 0);
    foreach ($arr as $key2=>$value2) {
        if ($key2 == $key) # If it's the same element
            continue;
        if ($value2 > $value) {
            if ($key2 < $key)
                $out[0]++;
            else
                $out[1]++;
        }
    }
    $output[] = $out;
}

print_r($output);
```

See the output [here](https://eval.in/734632).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fix_array($array) {
    $return_array = array();

    foreach ($array as $i => $value){
        $left = array_slice($array, 0, $i);

        $count_left = count(array_filter($left, function($var) use($value){
            return $var > $value;
        }));

        $right = array_slice($array, $i + 1);

        $count_right = count(array_filter($right, function($var) use($value){
            return $var > $value;
        }));

        $return_array[] = [$count_left, $count_right];

    }

    return $return_array;
}

$arr = [9, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6];

$new_array = fix_array($arr);

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare it with left and right values. Try this:

```
$arr = [9, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6];
$total = count($arr);

$new_arr=array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  $left = 0;
  $right = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) { 
    if($key > $i && $arr[$i] > $arr[$key])
    {
      $left++;
    }
    elseif ($key < $i && $arr[$i] > $arr[$key]) {
      $right++;
    }
  }
  $new_arr[]=[$left,$right];

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code using array_walk()

```
<?php

$arr = [9, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6];

$finalArray =[];
array_walk($arr, function($value,$key) use(&$finalArray,&$arr) {

$param ['pre_val']=0;
$param ['post_val']=0;
$param ['current_index'] = $key;
$param ['current_value'] = $value;
$arr2 = $arr;
array_walk($arr2, function(&$value,$key) use(&$finalArray,&$param) {
    if($key < $param['current_index']){
        if($value > $param['current_value']){$param['pre_val'] ++;}
    }else{
        if($value > $param['current_value']){$param['post_val'] ++;}
    }
    $finalArray[$param['current_index']][0] = $param['pre_val'];
    $finalArray[$param['current_index']][1] = $param['post_val'];
  });
});


print_r($finalArray);
```